# How to transfer GeoQuerySet.distance(geom, **kwargs) from Django 1.8 to Django 3.0?

Tags: django, geodjango, django-1.8, django-2.2, django-3.0

I found this example in the Django 1.8 documentation. And it’s very important for me to follow the same steps, but in Django 3.0 (or 2.2).

```
class AustraliaCity(NamedModel):
    point = models.PointField()
    radius = models.IntegerField(default=10000)
    allowed_distance = models.FloatField(default=0.5)
```

```
pnt = AustraliaCity.objects.get(name='Hobart').point
for city in AustraliaCity.objects.distance(pnt): print(city.name, city.distance)
```

But AustraliaCity.objects.distance(pnt) causes an error in Django 3.0. AttributeError: 'AustraliaCity' object has no attribute 'distance'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/my_project/my_project/web.py", line 21, in show
    print(city.name, city.distance)
AttributeError: 'AustraliaCity' object has no attribute 'distance'
```

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Is the error in the query or is it in the print?

Comment: @IainShelvington   error in both query and print

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: @IainShelvington Updated a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with an annotation

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
for city in AustraliaCity.objects.annotate(distance=Distance('point', pnt)):
    print(city.name, city.distance)
```